# Matplotlib: Subplots with Dates Not Consistent Formatting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, formatting, graphing

The formatting of of x-axis ticks are not consistent between the different subplots. I've tried manipulating by increasing space and formatting the dates, but nothing is working. All of the records in the date column are in fact dates.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10,10), sharey='all')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.3)
daily_performance[0].plot(x='date', y='return 1 day', kind='line', ax=ax[0,0])
daily_performance[1].plot(x='date', y='return 1 day', kind='line', ax=ax[0,1])
daily_performance[2].plot(x='date', y='return 1 day', kind='line', ax=ax[1,0])
daily_performance[3].plot(x='date', y='return 1 day', kind='line', ax=ax[1,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Sample Data shown below:

```
[        date  open        hi    lo   close  return 1 day  return 3 day  \
 0 2014-01-13  71.27  71.6000  69.49  70.12     -0.018340     -0.119869   
 1 2014-01-14  69.90  72.8200  69.58  72.67      0.036366     -0.013038   
 2 2014-01-15  72.74  73.4100  72.18  73.22      0.007568      0.025059   
 3 2014-01-16  73.16  73.4975  72.23  73.10     -0.001639      0.042499   
 4 2014-01-17  73.34  75.4500  73.06  75.42      0.031737      0.037842   

    return 5 day  
 0     -0.115986  
 1     -0.092306  
 2     -0.080959  
 3     -0.007198  
 4      0.055859  ,
         date   open        hi    lo    close  return 1 day  return 3 day  \
 5 2016-02-08  104.67  105.750  98.15  100.44     -0.045066     -0.097817   
 6 2016-02-09   99.70  101.160  94.01   96.28     -0.041418     -0.123293   
 7 2016-02-10   97.06   99.495  96.15   96.91      0.006543     -0.078627   
 8 2016-02-11   95.00   96.570  93.45   94.71     -0.022701     -0.057049   
 9 2016-02-12   95.51   99.040  94.36   98.63      0.041390      0.024408   

    return 5 day  
 5     -0.167302  
 6     -0.164164  
 7     -0.129525  
 8     -0.137589  
 9     -0.062274  ,
          date   open        hi     lo    close  return 1 day  return 3 day  \
 10 2016-02-09   99.70  101.160   94.01   96.28     -0.041418     -0.123293   
 11 2016-02-10   97.06   99.495   96.15   96.91      0.006543     -0.078627   
 12 2016-02-11   95.00   96.570   93.45   94.71     -0.022701     -0.057049   
 13 2016-02-12   95.51   99.040   94.36   98.63      0.041390      0.024408   
 14 2016-02-16  100.10  105.480  100.00  104.15      0.055967      0.074708   

     return 5 day  
 10     -0.164164  
 11     -0.129525  
 12     -0.137589  
 13     -0.062274  
 14      0.036937  ,
          date   open        hi     lo    close  return 1 day  return 3 day  \
 15 2016-02-10   97.06   99.495   96.15   96.91      0.006543     -0.078627   
 16 2016-02-11   95.00   96.570   93.45   94.71     -0.022701     -0.057049   
 17 2016-02-12   95.51   99.040   94.36   98.63      0.041390      0.024408   
 18 2016-02-16  100.10  105.480  100.00  104.15      0.055967      0.074708   
 19 2016-02-17  105.31  107.570  103.32  105.37      0.011714      0.112554   

     return 5 day  
 15     -0.129525  
 16     -0.137589  
 17     -0.062274  
 18      0.036937  
 19      0.094412  ]
```

Comment: Check the dtypes of 'date' in all your dataframes.  I suspect that you have a mixture of datetime dtypes and 'object' i.e. string dtypes.

Comment: My mistake - just verified that the dates are all datetimes

Comment: I fear that this is just a very nice example of pandas going crazy with date formatting. Yet, would you be able to use a [mcve] in the question, such that this can be reproduced? ([How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))